# how to apply colors or texture image to LoopingSelector when selected in Windows Phone?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

How to apply color or background image inside LoopingSelector? There are no option for this control in properties. Then how can we apply color to this control as shown in the below picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An option would be for you to modify the loopingselector style, modify the Grid background in the style template

```
<Style TargetType="primitives:LoopingSelectorItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="root" Opacity="0" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".6" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="background" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transform"/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>

                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="background" Margin="2" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneInactiveBrush}" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>

                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneInactiveBrush}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

These effects can be done easy in blend with Storyboad

Comment: Can you put more description please for your answer.